# Not sure how to get variable output files to build with Makefile

Tags: build, sass, makefile, gnu-make

### Update

Added my current makefile, it doesn't look too pretty but it compiles. Problem is, it won't re-compile if any _*.scss files are changed. How do I get this to recognize that a _*.scss source updated and needs to recompile?

Are there places I can simplify this code?

The directory structure is as follows:

```
.
├── Makefile
├── src
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── style.scss
│   │   ├── print.scss
│   │   ├── scss
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── fonts
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── html
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── img
│   │   ├── logo.png
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── Chart.min.js
│   │   └── ...
│   └── pie2
│       └── PIE_uncompressed.htc
└── www
    ├── css
    ├── fonts
    │   └── ...
    ├── img
    │   ├── logo.png
    │   └── ...
    ├── js
    └── pie2
        └── PIE_uncompressed.htc

23 directories, 457 files
```

Are my variable output names causing issues? Can I simplify the outputs without losing the functionality I have? Am I totally off track with this makefile as is? Maybe there's a way better way to do what I'm attempting to do?

Makefile

```
#commands
SASSC := sassc -l -m -t expanded
COPYC := rsync -rupE
RMC := rm -rf
ZIPC := zip
IMAGEOPTIMIZEC := imageoptim --directory
PREFIXERC := autoprefixer
COMPRESSC := yuicompressor

PACKAGE_NAME := cbf_style.zip

#base dirs
OUTPUT_ROOT := www
SRC_DIR := src

#output directories
CSS := $(OUTPUT_ROOT)/css
FONTS := $(OUTPUT_ROOT)/fonts
HTML := $(OUTPUT_ROOT)
IMG := $(OUTPUT_ROOT)/img
JS := $(OUTPUT_ROOT)/js
PIE := $(OUTPUT_ROOT)/pie
PIE2 := $(OUTPUT_ROOT)/pie2

#src directories
CSS_SRC := $(SRC_DIR)/css
SASS := $(SRC_DIR)/css/scss
FONTS_SRC := $(SRC_DIR)/fonts
HTML_SRC := $(SRC_DIR)/html
IMG_SRC := $(SRC_DIR)/img
JS_SRC := $(SRC_DIR)/js
PIE_SRC := $(SRC_DIR)/pie
PIE2_SRC := $(SRC_DIR)/pie2

#lists
MAKE_DIRS := $(OUTPUT_ROOT) $(CSS)
COPY_DIRS := $(FONTS_SRC) $(PIE_SRC) $(PIE2_SRC) $(JS_SRC)

CLEANABLE := $(CSS) $(FONTS) $(IMG) $(JS) $(PIE) $(PIE2) $(PACKAGE_NAME) $(wildcard $(HTML)/%.html)

PACKAGE_DIRS := $(CSS) $(FONTS) $(IMG) $(JS) $(PIE) $(PIE2)

CSS_TO_GENERATE = $(patsubst $(CSS_SRC)/%.scss, %.css, $(wildcard $(CSS_SRC)/*.scss))

HTML_FILES := $(wildcard $(HTML_SRC)/*.html)
JS_FILES := $(shell find src/js -maxdepth 1 -name *.js -execdir echo '{}' ';')

CSS_MIN := $(patsubst %.css, %.min.css, $(wildcard $(CSS)/*.css))
JS_MIN := $(patsubst %.js, %.min.js, $(wildcard $(JS)/*.js))

MAKEFILE_PATH := $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)))
MAKEFILE_DIR := $(patsubst %/,%,$(dir $(MAKEFILE_PATH)))

#methods are not files
.PHONY: build setup test watch package compress clean copy imgoptim all $(COPY_DIRS) $(MAKE_DIRS) $(CSS_TO_GENERATE) $(IMG) $(HTML_FILES) $(CSS_MIN) $(JS_MIN)

#methods
all: clean compile test package
install: setup compile
check: test

clean:
    @$(RMC) $(CLEANABLE)

compile: setup $(CSS_TO_GENERATE)

setup: $(MAKE_DIRS) $(COPY_DIRS) $(IMG) $(HTML_FILES)

build: package

test: compile
    @open "$(OUTPUT_ROOT)/index.html"
    @make watch

watch:
    watchman watch $(shell pwd)/$(SRC_DIR)
    watchman -- trigger $(shell pwd) remake src/css/*.scss src/css/scss/*.scss src/js/*.js -- make compile

package: compile compress imgoptim
    $(ZIPC) -r -dd $(PACKAGE_NAME) $(PACKAGE_DIRS)

compress: $(CSS_MIN) $(JS_MIN)

imgoptim: $(IMG)
    $(IMAGEOPTIMIZEC) $<

$(COPY_DIRS):
    @$(COPYC) $@ $(OUTPUT_ROOT)/

$(MAKE_DIRS):
    @mkdir -p $@

$(HTML_FILES):
    @$(COPYC) $@ $(OUTPUT_ROOT)

$(CSS_TO_GENERATE):
    @make $(CSS)/$@

$(CSS_MIN): %.min.css: %.css
    $(COMPRESSC) $< > $@

$(JS_MIN): %.min.js: %.js
    $(COMPRESSC) $< > $@

%.css:
    $(SASSC) $(patsubst $(CSS)/%, $(CSS_SRC)/%.scss, $*) $*.css

$(CSS_SRC)/%.scss: $(SASS)/*.scss

%.min.css: %.css
    @echo "nothing here yet"

$(IMG): $(IMG_SRC) $(IMG_SRC)/*
    @$(COPYC) $< $(OUTPUT_ROOT)
```

Comment: It looks like using VPATH is probably a good start

Comment: I haven't had a chance to look at this in detail yet, though I plan to, so I can't say whether `VPATH` is a good idea or not but read [How Not to Use VPATH](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/) (written by the GNU Make Maintainer) before you attempt it to make sure you are doing it right.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that out, thanks!

Comment: None of your recipes define any prerequisites (the right hand side of the `:`). So make doesn't know that the output files are dependent on the input files so that it can know to remake them.

Comment: @EtanReisner isn't `imgoptim: $(IMG)` an example of a prereq?

Comment: Yes, I was being slightly hyperbolic. There are a few instances of prerequisites. But those are mostly the `.PHONY` targets which are always going to run anyway. And actually it may not be as bad as I thought but the way you have your makefile written is a bit complicated and splits parts of rules in ways that make it harder to read. Run `make -d` when it fails to update and make will show you the prerequisites it checks for each target file (that should show you where it is failing to look at the right prereqs).

Comment: @EtanReisner awesome, I'll do that! I figured it was probably too complicated - it started feeling like it was held together by duct tape and bailing wire